# How does one make a 2d lighting system in XNA?

Tags: c#, xna, hlsl, lighting

I've spent a day becoming familiar with HlSL, in order to write a shader for a lighting system in my 2D xna game.

However, I feel lost now, because I don't have a clue how to write the shader. I've looked at a few tutorials, but they are either dealing with 3D stuff, or doing too complicated things, or just hard to follow / learn from.

I just want a lighting system that makes it possible for light to collide with objects I want it too, and cast shadows.

How do I do this?

Comment: Do you mean something like [this](http://youtu.be/N-WTQXGaLsU)? Because I can assure that it involves a *lot* of things that are "complicated" and "hard to follow". Normally I avoid telling people that something is too hard for them (especially on Stack Overflow where their questions can be of utility to others in the future). But in this case, based on your recent stream of very beginner-level questions, I feel compelled to urge you to try and master the basics first. Experiment with some of the shader samples on [App Hub](http://create.msdn.com/) - modify them and learn how they work.

Comment: @AndrewRussell, yes I do mean something like that. And I have written grayscale effects and minor things as practice, so what you suggested does not help me.

Comment: My point was that you're asking for something contradictory - you want something that isn't hard/complicated. Unfortunately you can't really do this without a lot of complication. That being said - the method I use in Dark is similar to [this one](http://www.gamedev.net/page/reference/index.html/_/technical/graphics-programming-and-theory/dynamic-2d-soft-shadows-r2032) - which is a lot of maths, plus a *crapload* of trickery to make it happen in a vertex shader. If you're serious about pursuing this, start with the maths and get it working on the CPU first, before moving it to HLSL.